# How does iOS know if a web site is restricted?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I don't add these web sites to the restricted list. Is the iPhone sending every page I visit to Apple? Random surfing will encounter a random  restricted site. In this case it renders this app broken because the 'allow' link doesn't work. Setting is currently set to limit adult content which allows me to use a white list and blacklist. I never added this site to blacklist. I only blacklist 3 sites.

[image]

How does iOS know that a website is restricted? Does it send it every page I visit to Apple?

How does iOS know if a website is restricted? Does it send it every page I visit to Apple?

See this is the BS I'm talking about:

[image]

iOS 10.1.1

Comment: Do you use any content blockers?

Comment: Have you checked your Restrictions in Settings?

Comment: No I don't use a content blocker. No I did not add this website to my restricted list as mentioned in the question.  Even news websites show up as restricted when I have never visited them before.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the specific website, I was speaking of Restrictions in general.  Please include in your question a screenshot of your Restrictions in Settings, that might help us figure out what the issue is.

Comment: An answer requires more technical details. How does it filter? How does it know? Is it magic? Is it telepathic? Or does it use keywords? Regular expressions? Is it violating my privacy and sending domains, sites, pages to a central server?

Answer (score 2):

Settings → Restrictions → Websites and select your preferred option for Allowed Websites.

[image]

Comment: That is way too restrictive. I would have to pre-enter the domain of every website that I wish to visit.  It is currently set to limit adult content which allows me to use a white list and blacklist.

Comment: @Chloe I don't understand your question then. If you wish to visit all websites, select All Websites. To Limit Adult Content by "apply[ing] a filter that tries to prevent users from viewing websites with adult content in Safari", choose that option, and add any websites you wish to be able to visit to the whitelist.

Comment: I wish to use a blacklist. My question appears quite clear. It's in the title. I don't know how to rephrase it for non-English speakers. Basically my question is "How does Apple/iOS know if a web site is restricted?" I'm sorry, this answer doesn't really answer my question. Does the phone keep a system blacklist of every possible web page? Is that how it knows? Please give me more technical details.

Comment: And my question was "how does it work", not "how can I limit the web sites I visit."

Answer (score 1):

As I guess you know, iOS limits websites based on the options you've selected in Settings > General > Restrictions > Websites.

As @grgarside shows with the screenshot in their answer, with Restrictions you can either:

- Allow all websites
- Limit Adult Content
- Allow specific websites only

By using these settings you can also set whitelists etc.

Based on your question, I assume you've limited adult content and every so often you'll try accessing a site that iOS has restricted.

With the *Limit Adult Content* filter enabled, there are several layers of filtering applied by iOS to web browsing. Apple has achieved this via a number of methods:

- Applying an automatic filter layer to prevent direct access to many adult sites
- Enabling the various search engine based filtering options to prevent inappropriate terms from being queried independently
- Adopting the likes of [Google SafeSearch](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and similar from [Bing](https://help.bing.microsoft.com/#apex/18/en-US/10003/0), [Yahoo](https://au.help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2247.html?guccounter=1), and others
- The prevention of web searches for a wide variety of terms.

In your question you offered a single example via the Yanflex screenshot. However, since Yanflex is only a 3rd party method of accessing Cragslist, the likelihood in this specific case is that iOS has restricted something from the Craigslist servers. This is not surprising, as specific individual pages on Craigslist regularly appear in block lists because of their content.

The only way around this is when you encounter a specific page that is blocked that you don't want blocked, you will need to specifically allow it by going to Settings > General > Restrictions > Websites > Limit Adult Content and adding it to the *Always Allow* list. That is assuming you have enabled *Limit Adult Content* to begin with.

Comment: Does my phone send every web page I visit to Apple, Google, Bing, Yahoo, or others so it decides to block it? What are the keywords that it blocks?

Comment: No. If you'd like to prove this to yourself, do this simple test. First of all enable Limit Adult Content in your Restrictions. Then launch Safari and directly enter a URL into the address bar that you know is _adult_ in nature and you will see it is blocked immediately with a message saying “You cannot browse this page at "URL" because it is restricted”. This happens instantly without the need to send every web page you visit to either Apple, Google, Bing or Yahoo. Similarly, performing adult centric web searches are blocked directly, with no search results being returned.

Comment: So you are saying that the name of every single adult web site is stored in my phone so it knows what to block? How do you explain blocking of this site?

Comment: No, I'm not. Notice how it's labelled **_Limit_ Adult Content**, because iOS website restrictions are not 100% perfect at blocking all inappropriate content. It's also not designed to block only pornographic sites, but as many sites as possible relating to adult themed material (that's why Apple often gets accused of making its filter too strong). This filtering is very effective, but not perfect. I have not personally worked on iOS itself, but I imagine part of the filtering process involves running a check of sites being visited against a master list that is regularly updated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've answered your questions: 1. _How does iOS know if a website is restricted?_ 2. _Does it send every page I visit to Apple?_ In terms of the issue you're now trying to cover, that's really a separate issue. I notice you edited your question so I did a test on my iPhone 6s running iOS 10.2 and enabled _Limit Adult Content_ in restrictions. I had **no** problems visiting apple.stackexchange.com or yanflex.com (although I don't know the _exact_ page on yanflex you were trying to visit. This implies you have something specific to your scenario that is affecting your usage.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. You said that it uses search engine filtering but it doesn't send the page to search engines. You said it  uses an automatic filter layer but it doesn't use keywords. You said it checks against a master list but the master list is not  on the phone nor does it send the page to Apple to check. Somehow it just magically knows.

Comment: The search engine filtering is about the fact that conducting searches on certain keywords won't produce results. It's not about blocking specific websites, but about preventing the search altogether and therefore blocking websites that would match the banned criteria. For example, if you have Limit Adult Content enabled, searching for "Blow Job" will not work as the search results and associated websites are blocked because the term "Blow Job" is restricted by the Content Filter **built into iOS**, so it's not even sent to a search engine or, if it is, all the results are blocked!

Comment: But searching the term "Blow Job" will work if Limit Adult Content isn't enabled because it is then sent to a search engine and/or the results aren't blocked! Finally, can you show me where I said the automatic filter layer doesn't use keywords, or where I said the master list was not on the phone? I never said these things, because it does use keywords and the Content Filter is on the device!  The Content Filter also includes such things as specific websites, not just keywords. I'm sorry if I haven't explained all of this very well, but no it doesn't just magically happen.

Comment: What do you mean by "Adopting the likes of Google SafeSearch and similar from Bing, Yahoo, and others"? Can you give several examples of sites and how this process works?

Comment: @Chloe Thanks for the comment. I've edited my answer to add links to what I was referring to. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hmm, that is only when you search for something using one of those services, and the filter is only for results on those web sites: Google "filter explicit search results *on Google*"; Bing: "SafeSearch helps keep adult content out of your *search results*". It doesn't have anything to do with the iOS mobile Safari visiting random pages.

Comment: @Chloe That's correct if you're using a browser on a device to conduct the search. However, with the Limit Adult Content filter enabled *within* iOS a number of filtering layers are automatically enabled. For example, if you have Bing selected as your default search engine for Safari (see Settings > Safari > Search Engine) then iOS will use your settings (e.g. the Limit Adult Content filter) to employ a range of layers including Bing's SafeSearch in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11 this has changed as the restrictions page has been removed.

Updated answer:

Go to Settings-> Screen time -> Turn it on if necessary-> Content & Privacy restrictions -> Content Restrictions-> Web Content.

Screen:

[image: Screen]

You can then choose between Limit adult websites which automatically blocks some websites, you can add to the list or allowed websites only which blocks all websites not in the allowed list.

Comment: How does it know whether to block a website? How does it decide to block apple.stackexchange.com with 'Limit Adult Websites'? Can you give several examples of how it decides whether to block or not?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with Safari blocking Google searches at random despite not having any filters on. When I went to Settings/ Screen Time/ Turn Off Screen Time the problem stopped. I believe I had previously signed into Screen Time under 'This is My Child's Phone' by accident. I didn't have any issues with Safari after I signed back into Screen Time under 'This is My Phone'. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I don't have Screen Time.