# Why is a new website/domain restricted on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, parental-controls

**Edit 1:** I'm sorry, but the answers provided in the [duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264864/how-does-ios-know-if-a-web-site-is-restricted) do not answer this question.

*To clarify:* I'm not asking how to whitelist a domain, I'm asking WHY a domain is blacklisted - seemingly without reason - in the first place when no explicit nor mature content can be found on it. It's imperative that the website can be acccessed on any iOS device, even if web content restrictions are in place, with no further user intervention.

**EDIT 2:** I've found that not all pages on our domain are blocked by this setting, so it seems iOS blocks a page based on specific content (words, images, etc.), maybe even certain HTML. Would be grand to know what exactly triggers the block.

**EDIT 3:** it's definitely the content. Once I remove all the main content from our website and just leave the header, footer, HTML tags, scripts etc. in tact, the website is accessible even with "Limit Adult Content" setting turned on. I've scoured the content but can't fathom what exactly causes this. The website text is in German (the HTML lang tag is set accordingly) and there's imo literally nothing that could be seen as adult content.
Guess we'll just have to get in touch with Apple to figure this one out. Thanks though!

---

**Original question:**

I just launched a new website for a client. The website is aimed at teenagers from 12-14 and doesn't contain any explicit content whatsoever.

If web page content restriction are turned on in iOS, the website cannot be accessed with Safari and the following message is displayed instead:

```
You cannot browse this page at  
"domain.com"
because it is restricted
```

Why does this happen and what can we do about it?
This makes no sense. The domain name in question is brand new, hasn't been used before and isn't on any blacklists as far as I can tell.

Any help is appreciated, we really need to get this website rated appropriately.

Comment: If I understand your edit correctly, you have "Limit Adult Content" enabled, your website can't be accessed, and you want to know what you need to do to get your website off whatever data basis Apple uses to identify potential adult content? This is rather close to the duplicate question, and partially covered in some of the answers. AFAIK Apple hasn't published any details about this, so contacting Apple directly might be the better approach here.

Comment: @nohillside yes, I do have "Limit Adult Content" enabled, but only for testing purposes. The website is a portal aimed at teenagers. As many teenagers use iOS devices with "Limit Adult Content" enabled by parents/guardians, it's imperative for our business to not be restricted by this setting. 
I've read the other question and all the answer before posting this question; while the question is similar, none of the responses there answer what I'm asking :) but maybe you're right, might be best to contact Apple directly. Can't see us getting an answer there either though, but worth a try.

Comment: @nohillside btw, I've found that not all pages on our domain are blocked by this setting, so it seems iOS blocks a page based on specific content (words, images, etc.), maybe even certain HTML. Would be grand to know what exactly triggers this.