# What can I do as a website admin to get my site whitelisted from Apple parental controls?

Tags: ios, safari, parental-controls

I work for a governmental website where by nature there is no explicit content whatsoever.

If web page content restriction is turned on in iOS, some parts of the site cannot be accessed with Safari, instead the following message is displayed:

> You cannot browse this page at "domain.com" because it is restricted

I have contacted Apple support but they seem to have a hard time to answer with actionable advice. Anyone else have similar experiences apart from this guy: [Why is a new website/domain restricted on iOS Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355875/why-is-a-new-website-domain-restricted-on-ios-safari) Mine are very similar, the answers to his question seem insufficient to me too.

Help would be greatly appreciated.